# How to move 4 objects symmetrically outward/inward on the same origin?

Tags: modeling, mirror, origin

I have 4 cubes symmetrically placed at the 4 corners of a plane and I want to move them along the x/y axis outward/inward the center of the plane witch is also the origin of the 4 cubes?

Here is the Mirrored Object i would like to use:
[image]

Comment: in Object mode you have the Manipulate Center Points option that allows you to do that but in Edit mode I don't think you have any direct way to do this operation, so I guess you'll have to find an indirect trick, like for example separating your 4 cubes in four different objects and using the Manipulate Center Points option then ctrl J to bring them back in the same object, or using the grid, or using the snap tool to snap the cubes to some vertices...

Comment: You saved my day! Is there a way to do the same on a mirrored object ?

Comment: please show some screenshots

Comment: Manipulate center point work perfectly with 4 differents objects.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfQp5.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfQp5.gif)

Comment: I modified my answer to have a gif that shows this working.

Comment: Here's a guy using it in version 2.76:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GgyUyYlxrM

Answer (score 1):

Take one of the cubes symmetrically placed on the plane and mirror it on the x and y axis.  Go to the mirror modifier and set the mirror object as the plane (which they will be placed on at the four corners).  Now if you go into edit mode you can select the one cube and move it to one corner, and the mirrored cubes will move symmetrically to the other corners.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[image: I'm telling you, it works]

- Select the objects. Right click and choose Set Origin>Origin To
  Geometry.
- In the pivot point menu set the pivot to Median Point and toggle Only Origins on.
- Scale the objects in the axis that you want to spread them apart.

You may want to snap the cursor to the origin location that the four objects are sharing first, and when you're done scaling the origins, right click>Set Origin>Origin To 3D Cursor to get the origins back where you have them now. Note that if the origins weren't all in the same location like they are now, you could skip the first step. Since they are currently 0 meters apart, scaling the origins has no effect since anything times zero is still zero.

Comment: That's great but is there a way to scale them on X/Y simultaneously. So I can move them constrained by the plane not only by one axis?

Comment: Yes. S key for scale, then shift+z key to constrain to the xy plane. If you use the scale gizmo or active tool, you can drag the xy plane part of the gizmo, or shift+drag the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Blender 4.0.2

- Select all the objects
- Set the origin to gemometry for selected objects
- Set the pivot point to median point
- In *Tools > Options > Transform > Affect Only Location*
- Scale objects as desired (I just used default key binding <kbd>S</kbd> in *Object Mode*)

[image]

[image]